# system verilog assertion disable condition

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have this assertion in order to check clk freq:

```
assert property clk_freq;
int cnt;
@(posedge fast_clk, clk_1MHz) disable_iff(!enable_check)
($rose(clk_1MHz), cnt=0) |=> (!$rose(clk_1MHz),cnt++) [*0:$] ##1 $rose(clk_1MHz), cnt==fast_clk_freq;
endproperty
```

fast_clk starts to toggle during (not from beginning) of the simulation after disable_check is asserted.
The problem is that it seems that the assertion ignores the `disable_iff`
Question: is a $rose(clk_1Mhz) event "registered" even though the assertion is disabled (or am I missing something else ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `disable_iff` keywords, it is `disable iff` (without the underscore).  Properties can have local variables but the local variables cannot be defined inline with `assert`. Separate the property definition and the assertion instantiation.

The clock sampling doesn't seem to be correct. `@(posedge fast_clk, clk_1MHz)` mean on rising fast_clk or any change to clk_1MHz. clk_1MHz is the sampled data value, therefore it should not be a clock.

`$rose(clk_1MHz), cnt==fast_clk_freq` is ilegal syntax, sugest: `$rose(clk_1MHz) ##0 cnt==fast_clk_freq`

Suggested property definition and the assertion instantiation:

```
property p_clk_freq;
int cnt;
@(posedge fast_clk) disable iff(!enable_check)
($rose(clk_1MHz), cnt=0) |=> (!$rose(clk_1MHz),cnt++)[*0:$] ##1 $rose(clk_1MHz) ##0 cnt==fast_clk_freq;
endproperty

a_clk_freq : assert property(p_clk_freq);
```

For more on assertions refer to section 16 of [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html).

Comment: after debug I suspect also another issue : If `enable_check` asserted  between `clk_1MHz` posedges, the assertion still begins to "count" i.e. the first `$rose` is satisfied **even though it occurred while `enable_check` was low.** is this (unexpected) behavior compatible with the standard ?